# Adding relationships efficiently. Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, relationship

I have a CSV of around 5 million rows and two columns: 'client', 'product'.
Each client is an ID in my neo4j graph and the same for the product.
We can have all types of duplications and this is fine.
I have the following code in python:

```
j=1
batch_size=500
nbatch=len(client_product)//batch_size+1
for i in range(0,len(client_product),batch_size):
    j+=1
    print(f"{j}/{nbatch}")
    batch = client_product.iloc[i:i + batch_size]
    my_dict = batch.to_dict('records')
    my_dict_str = str(my_dict)
    my_dict_str=dictToPropertiesSingleValue(str(my_dict))
    tq=f"""UNWIND {my_dict_str} AS row
    MATCH (n:client), (k:product)
    WHERE ID(n) = row.client_ID AND ID(k) = row.product_ID
    CREATE (n)-[r:client_product]->(k)
    return count(r)"""
    runq(tq)
```

The part in the middle

```
my_dict = batch.to_dict('records')
my_dict_str = str(my_dict)
my_dict_str=dictToPropertiesSingleValue(str(my_dict))
```

is formatting a dictionary in a list readable by neo4j. Like:

```
[ {client_ID: 918906,product_ID: 40320},
 {client_ID: 918920,product_ID: 40320},
 {client_ID: 918921,product_ID: 40320},
 {client_ID: 918953,product_ID: 40321},
 {client_ID: 918955,product_ID: 40322},
 {client_ID: 918960,product_ID: 40323},
 {client_ID: 919018,product_ID: 40323},
 {client_ID: 919517,product_ID: 40323},
 {client_ID: 919702,product_ID: 40323},
 {client_ID: 919703,product_ID: 40324},
 {client_ID: 919743,product_ID: 40324},
 {client_ID: 919744,product_ID: 40324},
 {client_ID: 919745,product_ID: 40324},
 {client_ID: 919764,product_ID: 40325}]
```

I am really struggling on finding a faster way to push these. It makes sense that pushing a few million relationships should take a few minutes but not 4 hours like it does for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Things that could help: 1. slightly increase the batch size 2. have a look at https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/neo4j-python-driver-rust-ext 3. don't embed the rows as string in your query, but use query parameters (generally a good habit, also avoids injection vulnerabilities) 4. avoid repeating the keys in your rows. Each row contains `client_ID` and `product_ID` which will be transmitted. Maybe use a list with two integers instead. Less readable, yes, but also much less data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write special code to make 10K individual Cypher queries (which is why it takes so long). You can just make a single query that uses the [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) clause, which is specifically designed to import directly from the CSV data. You can also use [CALL subqueries in transactions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/subqueries-in-transactions/) to support [importing large amounts of data](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) in batches.

For example (I use a batch size of 5000, but you can try different values to see which works faster for you):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///client_product.csv' AS r
CALL {
  WITH r
  MATCH (n), (k)
  WHERE ID(n) = r.client_ID AND ID(k) = r.product_ID
  CREATE (n)-[:client_product]->(k)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 5000 rows
```

Notes:

1. Above query assumes the CSV file starts with a header row (e.g., "client_ID,product_ID").
2. If loading from a local file, see the "Configuration settings for file URLs" section of the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/).
3. `LOAD CSV` can also load from an http URL if the CSV file is available remotely.
4. If you need to avoid making duplicate relationships, use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of `CREATE` (but it will be a bit slower).